# Accessing Dynamics CRM 2011 Contacts URL using phone number

Tags: asp.net, dynamics-crm-2011

I am working with Dynamics CRM 2011 on premise. I wanted to find out how we can open a particular contact using a URL by using a phone number.

The URL looks like this:

server/organization/main.aspx?etc=2&id=***%7b203C4B46-5822-E211-B26E-000C295CF877%7d***&pagetype=entityrecord

I wanted to know how this ID is created and whether using the search field like phone number this ID can be found/called.

Answer (score 1):

I found a similar question posted to the Microsoft Dynamics CRM community forum. There was a useful response from a Microsoft CRM support engineer. I'll quote it below.

https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/87837

> In order to open a specific record in CRM you must provide the unique
>   identifier for that record type.
>
> So for account records it would be accountId. You would not be able to
>   build a URL for an account edit form that provides some other value
>   for some other attribute and have it open a specific record.
>
> The Microsoft Dynamics CRM SDK provides a section specifically for how
>   to open records by building a URL.
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx
>
> How you get to a specific record in CRM depends upon in what context
>   you are accessing CRM data.
>
> If you are in the web client, you could use Advanced Find to look for
>   Accounts and add a filter condition to search for records with a
>   specific telephone number.
>
> If you need to open a CRM account directly by only knowing the
>   telephone number for an account, again you would need to leverage the
>   CRM SDK.
>
> You could create an HTML web resource and in the query string for the
>   HTML web resource provide the data to identify the account (in your
>   case some telephone number). On the HTML page you could have some
>   onload javascript that calls into the OrganizationData.svc ODATA
>   service and query for accounts based on the criteria you have provided
>   on the query string, then you could build up the URL for the account
>   (since now you have access to the accountId) and redirect from your
>   HTML web resource to the URL for the account.

Answer (score 0):

The ID is assigned by CRM at creation. You will need to search for the ID first using web service methods (specifically a RetrieveMultiple), then you can just build up the url.

This thread has an example of doing this in CRM 4: [Retrieving a single Guid in CRM 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952918/retrieving-a-single-guid-in-crm-4-0/12954643#12954643).

Then you will just need to build a version using the CRM 2011 SDK (though you could use the CRM 4 methods as they are still supported).

Resources:

[Build Queries with QueryExpression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328300.aspx)

Comment: In my applicaion given a particular phone number i need to open the contact page of the person whose number is provided by calling a URL how do i open that contact page by supplying phone number in that URL??

Comment: You cant, you have to search for the record id first.