# Can't convert nor cast BusinessEntity to DynamicEntity

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4, query-expressions

I'm getting error when I try to execute the last line in [this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952918/retrieving-a-single-guid-in-crm-4-0). I run the following code:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
{
  LogicalName = "contact",
  ...
}

BusinessEntityCollection response = ServiceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(query);
Logify("count: " + response.BusinessEntities.Count);
BusinessEntity piff= response.BusinessEntities.First();
Logify("piff: " + (piff != null));

DynamicEntity poof = response.BusinessEntities.First() as DynamicEntity;
Logify("poof: " + (poof != null));
```

The count is 1, so the call is performed correctly and yields something. According to the log, *piff* isn't null, so it contains something. However, after the conversion (which is required in order to access the fields of the entity), I get it to be *null* (or I get an *Exception* when trying to explicitly cast the shabang).

The exception is:

> Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.Crm.SdkTypeProxy.contact' to type 'Microsoft.Crm.Sdk.DynamicEntity'.

What to do?!

Comment: When you use `as <type>` there are only 2 outcomes.  Either type, or null.  The conversion is failing so `poof` is null.  Are you sure that a `BusinessEntity` can be cast as a `DynamicEntity`?

Comment: @paqogomez I'm sure it can't be because the computer says so. However, it's **supposed** to work as the example I link to shows. In either case, I need to access a field on the fetched entity and I'm not sure how to if I can't cast the stupid thing.

Comment: 2 questions. First, does `BusinessEntity` inherit from `DynamicEntity`. Second, if you call response.BusinessEntities two times in a row, does it work? To test the second question, can you try poof before piff?

Comment: the exact exception you get?

Comment: @DavidG #1: Yes, as far I'm informed. #2: Yes, even if *First* would remove the first element, I've tested with responses of multiple entities.

Comment: @GuidoPreite Kindly, see the addition in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use RetrieveMultipleRequest. Reworked code:

```
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
{
    LogicalName = "contact",
    ...
}

RetrieveMultipleRequest rmr = new RetrieveMultipleRequest()
{
    Query = query,
    ReturnDynamicEntities = true
};

RetrieveMultipleResponse rmrresp = ServiceProxy.Execute(rmr) as RetrieveMultipleResponse;
BusinessEntityCollection response = rmrresp.BusinessEntityCollection;
Logify("count: " + response.BusinessEntities.Count);
BusinessEntity piff= response.BusinessEntities.First();
Logify("piff: " + (piff != null));

DynamicEntity poof = response.BusinessEntities.First() as DynamicEntity;
Logify("poof: " + (poof != null));
```